Type of presence sensor for room with heat source
I need a presence sensor for a small room (4m2). The sensor should be able to turn on the light when someone enters and stays in the room. It needs to be recessed ceiling mounted and should not be triggered by the washer/dryer in the room. I am concerned about false alarms caused by the heat emitted from the washer/dryer, so I'm hesitant about using a PIR sensor. Can you recommend a type of sensor that would meet these requirements?

In my experience, IR motion sensors do indeed have trouble with rapidly changing/moving heat sources. I was hoping to use them in my house, and found that they picked up heated air masses from my minisplits. Frustrating.
There are systems which try to sense occupancy by measuring radio reflections in the WiFi band, since bodies absorb some signal. I have no experience with them.

I had an office with an occupancy sensor and learned I had to wave my arms every 10 minutes or so to keep the lights on. Sitting and typing at the computer was not enough. Frustrating. Worse was the window-less secure space where the computer was around the corner from the sensor by the entrance, and you would be plunged into darkness except for the glow of the computer screen.

There are dual sensors based on both PIR+MW (microwave detection) used in alarm systems. But I don't know if there are such sensors for controlling light.

If the sensor exists, then with enough effort you could make it control a light. In the other hand, if it is being sold for safety and security purposes it may cost an order of magnitude more than a more basic sensor due to higher reliability requirements, plus the hardware and)or software needed to tie it to the light control. All I can suggest is to start shopping for a solution.
